# errors while downloading eclipse ADT from the site

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, adt

Its been 3 days I am trying to install Eclipse with ADT plugin. I downloaded eclipse last year , and I trying now to use it.
when I run the application , a popup said I have to upgrade eclipse and ADT to latest version.
I did some research over the net and they preferred If I download a fresh copy .
I went to [android devsite](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools)
and I download it , however when I extract the file I faced the below errors

```
  !   C:\Users\anameme\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip: Cannot create folder adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86\features\com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature_23.0.2.1259578\META-INF\maven\adt.group\com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature
      The filename or extension is too long.
```

-why I had such errors ? note that I download  it 3 times and I am facing the same errors. is it because the length name is long ?

My second problem is when I download eclipse(Version: 4.2.2
Build id: M20130204-1200) and I run it with ADT(version23.0.2 ) , I had in the rec/layout only main_activity.xml and I couldnt find fragment.xml . even when I create the project I only have main_activity. I am new to android dev  but framgment and main activity are different , so why it does not exists when I create android project ?

**what I want is a workable eclipse with ADT plugin so I can learn mobb app from android dev site** 
in the android developer site ( where they teach how to develop an app)

Comment: It's quite obvious. "Downloading 3 times" is not any kind of research, when error clearly states that Path name is too long. [It says here that maximum length is 256 characters](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/what-maximum-number-characters-filename-can-be)

Comment: @Marius I though the problem with the download , well then I have to rename the file extraction and it will be fine ?.

Comment: It looks like you have two problems in your post. Please separate this into two questions. 

Your first problem (The filename or extension is too long.) was answered in this StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724138/while-extracting-adt-bundle-windows-x86-64-20140702-this-error-from-windows-8/26963340#26963340. 

Even though the question says Windows 8, the solutions work for both Windows 7 and 8.