# While extracting adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702 this error from windows 8

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

****While extracting adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702 from windows 8 this error occurred**

```
(!   D:\Bela\Work\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip: Cannot create folder adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86\features\com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature_23.0.2.1259578\META-INF\maven\adt.group\com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature
    The filename or extension is too long.
!   D:\Bela\Work\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip: Cannot create adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86\features\com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature_23.0.2.1259578\META-INF\maven\adt.group\com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature\pom.xml
    Total path and file name length must not exceed 260 characters
    The system cannot find the path specified.
!   D:\Bela\Work\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip: Cannot create adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86\features\com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature_23.0.2.1259578\META-INF\maven\adt.group\com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature\pom.properties
    Total path and file name length must not exceed 260 characters
    The system cannot find the path specified.)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: please check your system 32bit/64bit and install accordingly

Comment: Don't extract it directly, create a directory with a name like "Android SDK" and extract inside it (not the adt-bundle-etc part, from inside it)

Comment: As you see from the name it's adt-bundle-windows-x86_64
so i guess its for both of the systems

Comment: Thanks Marco Acierno, it helped. that's what I wanted. I wasn't asking for judgments...

Comment: @Simon, remove that comment with the insulting undertone.

Comment: Make sure that you extract ADT so that there are no spaces in the path. Do not use directory names like `Andoid SDK`; better use `D:\Android`. Note that unzip will _"automatically"_ create the `D:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702` root directory.

Answer (score 12):

To further simplify the answer to this: the reason that you want to extract it to C: is that if you extract it to somewhere else (like you desktop) you will be adding characters to the file name. If you extract it as it is to the desktop, it will add "C:/users/username/desktop/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702" to the paths of all of the files and put you at risk for exceeding the max path name size. If you do it straight to C: (or any drive) and give it a short name like android, you will only add C:/android to the path.

Answer (score 5):

Had this same issue and no matter how I extracted it, tried to rename stuff, etc. I kept getting the error. I thought opening the archive (in WinRAR) and dragging out the subfolders inside the adt-bundle.... folder would reduce the character count but I kept getting the error. On a whim, I tried just right-clicking the archive, choosing Extract files... and selecting the C: drive (essentially what I was already trying to do by dragging the folder) and.... it worked!! Looks like whatever WinRAR does when you drag files to extract is different than using the Extract files... option.

Just wanted to put this here in case others run into the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to extract the file instead of the built-in Windows utility. 7-Zip will allow you to extract the file to anywhere on your machine.

This is a known problem on Windows 7 and Windows 8. See [Issue 72539:   eclipse adt bundle windows 7 64 bit will not unzip](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72539) on the Android Issue Tracker.

Comment: thanks for pointing to an actual filed bug. Java development system with randomly long org.mydogandcatalsowantdowritecode.com nested folders is fundamentally at odds with Windows filesystem deficiencies, but that doesn't excuse ADT releases with no basic testing at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with WinRAR.
There are two solutions:

1. **Right click** on archive - **Open with** - **Windows Explorer** - drag&drop files to any folder.
2. Open archive with WinRAR - Rename folder from `adt-bundle-<os_platform>` to `adt-bundle` -  drag&drop files to any folder.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. Move the archive to the root of your hard disk, like C:\
2. Rename the archive to adt.rar (strip the rest of the filename)
3. Rename the folder inside the archive also to adt (open the archive and rename the root directory)
4. Extract to anywhere you want

Info: The problem wasn't the destination path name, it was the source path name.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the ADT for Windows 7 on a 64 bit machine. I received this error a few times while trying to extract as well.

I resolved this by creating a folder in the C drive - C:\ADT and extracting to this location. I was able to extract without any further errors.

Answer (score 0):

just click "extract to" instead of drag&drop archive