# Try to extract the adt bundle. But file path is too long to extract

Tags: android, installation, adt, extract

I try to extract the abt bundle download from google site. When I tried to use rar to extract the files, there are file extraction error saying the total path and file name too long.

How can resolve this problem

Comment: which os do u have no may be problem of downlaod

Comment: I think this is answered in a previous thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724138/while-extracting-adt-bundle-windows-x86-64-20140702-this-error-from-windows-8